# how to create a postgresql instance using OAuth2Client in google using nodejs client library

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-authentication

i have a requirement for creating PostgreSQL instance using google SQL admin API, for the authentication, i want to use OAuth2Client in node js client library

```
    function first() { 
           const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
                  client_id,
                  client_secret,
                  redirect_uris[0]
                );
            var tkn = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code_from_another_user);
                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tkn);
    return oAuth2Client;
   });
    function second(oAuth2Client)
    {
            var req = {
                 project: prjName,
                  resource: {
                    databaseVersion: "POSTGRES_13",
                    name: name,
                    region: cregion ,
                    gceZone: czone,
                    settings: {*****}
                    rootPassword: "xxxxx",
                  },
                  auth: oAuth2Client,
                };
                var crpsql = await sqlAdmin.instances.insert(req);
                return crpsql;
    });


function mainexec()
{
 var a = first();
var b = second(a);
});
```

and i get this error

> Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback
> is set

here actually, i am trying to create  a PostgreSQL instance on other google account cloud platform with there consent using OAuth2Client access token method. anyone please help? any supporting documentation?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function first returns oAuth2Client as it is . But in the function second it is converted to JSON object automatically.
so changed the function named second like this

```
function second(oAuth2Client)
    {
var newoAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      oAuth2Client._clientId,
      oAuth2Client._clientSecret,
      oAuth2Client.redirectUri
    );
    var tokenObj = {
      access_token: oAuth2Client.credentials.tokens.access_token,
      refresh_token: oAuth2Client.credentials.tokens.refresh_token,
    };
    newoAuth2Client.credentials = tokenObj;
            var req = {
                 project: prjName,
                  resource: {
                    databaseVersion: "POSTGRES_13",
                    name: name,
                    region: cregion ,
                    gceZone: czone,
                    settings: {*****}
                    rootPassword: "xxxxx",
                  },
                  auth:  newoAuth2Client,
                };
                var crpsql = await sqlAdmin.instances.insert(req);
                return crpsql;
    });
```

it worked like a magic.